# How to drop a database with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm preparing a database creation script in Node.js and Mongoose.
How can I check if the database already exists, and if so, drop (delete) it using Mongoose?

I could not find a way to drop it with Mongoose.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453617/mongoose-js-remove-collection-or-db

Answer (score 177, accepted):

There is no method for dropping a collection from mongoose, the best you can do is remove the content of one :

```
Model.remove({}, function(err) { 
   console.log('collection removed') 
});
```

But there is a way to access the mongodb native javascript driver, which can be used for this

```
mongoose.connection.collections['collectionName'].drop( function(err) {
    console.log('collection dropped');
});
```

#### Warning

Make a backup before trying this in case anything goes wrong!

Comment: when I try the second option I get "cannot read property 'collectionName' of undefined"

Comment: You are right, sorry for that the correct code is mongoose.connection.collections['collectionName'].drop( function(err) { });

Comment: thanks, this works, but I still need to declare the schemas and all before calling it. isn't there something more brute force?

Comment: Since all collections are in the hash mongoose.connection.collections, you might simply list them for ( collection in mongoose.connection.collections ) { mongoose.connection.collections[collection].drop } ... smth similar

Comment: Also, you don't have to list the schema to access your collections from there, you just need a valid connection, without further mongoose.model declarations!

Comment: You've got a typo -- an extra comma after the function(err)... should be: mongoose.connection.collections['collectionName'].drop( function(err) {
    console.log('collection dropped');
});

Comment: Am i the only one that realized this answer does not address the question of how to drop a database. Its not asking to drop a collection its asking to drop a database..

Comment: For some reason, I get this error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'drop' of undefined`. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Oh I misclicked on downvote button, and I understood 15 minutes later :/ can you edit it please?

Comment: If you get "cannot read property 'collectionName' of undefined" try:mongoose.connection.collection(collectionName).drop(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("err:", err);
    }
});

Comment: "There is no method for dropping a collection from mongoose", first of all the OP wants to delete a database, not a colledtion, second the answer of @hellslam below works well.

Answer (score 98):

Mongoose will create a database if one does not already exist on connection, so once you make the connection, you can just query it to see if there is anything in it.

You can drop any database you are connected to:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
/* Connect to the DB */
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase',function(){
    /* Drop the DB */
    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
});
```

Comment: I tried `mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase()` but I found the db is still there? Do I miss something?

Comment: If you connected to it afterward it would be recreated, though empty. Were there any collections in it after you dropped it?

Comment: Are you using the same connection throughout, or creating multiple connections?

Comment: I found the `dropDatabase` invocation should be placed in the callback of `connect`, as `mongoose.connect('...', function() { ...dropDatabase()})`.

Comment: dropDatabase seems not work in some cases, but direct mongo command still can be used

`mongoose.connection.db.executeDbCommand( {dropDatabase:1},    function(err, result) {
     if (err) { console.log(err); }
     done();
});`

Answer (score 17):

If you modify @hellslam's solution like this then it will work

I use this technique to drop the Database after my integration tests

```
//CoffeeScript
mongoose = require "mongoose"
conn = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mydb")

conn.connection.db.dropDatabase()

//JavaScript
var conn, mongoose;
mongoose = require("mongoose");
conn = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mydb");

conn.connection.db.dropDatabase();
```

HTH at least it did for me, so I decided to share =)

Comment: is it possible to drop db with this? `db = mongoose.createConnection(cfg.mongo.uri, cfg.mongo.db);`

Comment: This was helpful, thanks! However, your variable names are a little misleading... `mongoose.connect` actually returns `mongoose`. Instead of `conn = mongoose.connect(...)` I'd write `mongoose.connect(...)` and then `conn = mongooose.connection`.

Comment: I don't think this code will always work because the `connect` is  asynchronous. So if the connection doesn't happen immediately, the dropDatabase() command will fail. That's why the other solutions above recommended putting the `dropDatabase` command in the callback to the `connect` statement or an `open` event handler.

Answer (score 9):

Tried @hellslam's and @silverfighter's answers. I found a race condition holding my tests back. In my case I'm running mocha tests and in the before function of the test I want to erase the entire DB. Here's what works for me.

```
var con = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase');
mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){
    con.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err, result){
        done();
    });
});
```

You can read more https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1469

Answer (score 8):

An updated answer, for 4.6.0+, if you have a preference for promises ([see docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', { useMongoClient: true })
.then((connection) => {
   connection.db.dropDatabase();
   // alternatively:
   // mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
});
```

I tested this code in my own code, using mongoose 4.13.6. Also, note the use of the `useMongoClient` option ([see docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client)). Docs indicate:

> Mongoose's default connection logic is deprecated as of 4.11.0. Please opt in to the new connection logic using the useMongoClient option, but make sure you test your connections first if you're upgrading an existing codebase!

Answer (score 6):

2020 update

make a new file call it drop.js i.e
and put inside

```
require('dotenv').config()
const url = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})


mongoose.connection.dropDatabase().then(
  async() => {
   
    try {
      mongoose.connection.close()
     
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }

 }
  
);
```

in your package.json

```
in your package.json 
 "scripts": {
    
    "drop": "node models/drop.js",
   
  }
```

run it on ur console and

Comment: if u just write mongoose.connection.dropDatabase you would  be stuck in and you conc will be still open so if you want to close it u shold handle the promise u got from it with try and catch to stay away from this err

Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 5):

The difficulty I've had with the other solutions is they rely on restarting your application if you want to get the indexes working again.

For my needs (i.e. being able to run a unit test the nukes all collections, then recreates them along with their indexes), I ended up implementing this solution:

*This relies on the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) libraries to assemble the indexes in parellel, it could be unwound if you're against that library but I leave that as an exerciser for the developer.*

```
mongoose.connection.db.executeDbCommand( {dropDatabase:1}, function(err, result) {
  var mongoPath = mongoose.connections[0].host + ':' + mongoose.connections[0].port + '/' + mongoose.connections[0].name
  //Kill the current connection, then re-establish it
  mongoose.connection.close()
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + mongoPath, function(err){
    var asyncFunctions = []

    //Loop through all the known schemas, and execute an ensureIndex to make sure we're clean
    _.each(mongoose.connections[0].base.modelSchemas, function(schema, key) {
      asyncFunctions.push(function(cb){
        mongoose.model(key, schema).ensureIndexes(function(){
          return cb()
        })
      })
    })

    async.parallel(asyncFunctions, function(err) {
      console.log('Done dumping all collections and recreating indexes')
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me as of Mongoose `v4.7.0`:

```
mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();
```

Answer (score 4):

**To empty a particular collection in a database:**

```
model.remove(function(err, p){
    if(err){ 
        throw err;
    } else{
        console.log('No Of Documents deleted:' + p);
    }
});
```

Note:

1. Choose a model referring to particular schema(schema of collection
   you wish to delete).
2. This operation will not delete collection name
   from database.
3. This deletes all the documents in a collection.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to drop your database in Mongoose depends on which version of Mongoose you are using. If you are using a version of Mongoose that 4.6.4 or newer, then this method added in that release is likely going to work fine for you:

```
mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();
```

In older releases this method did not exist. Instead, you were to use a direct MongoDB call:

```
mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
```

However, if this was run just after the database connection was created, it could possibly fail silently. This is related to the connection actually be asynchronous and not being set up yet when the command happens. This is not normally a problem for other Mongoose calls like `.find()`, which queue until the connection is open and then run.

If you look at the source code for the `dropDatabase()` shortcut that was added, you can see it was designed to solve this exact problem. It checks to see if the connection is open and ready. If so, it fires the command immediately. If not, it registers the command to run when the database connection has opened.

Some of the suggestions above recommend *always* putting your `dropDatabase` command in the `open` handler. But that only works in the case when the connection is not open yet.

```
Connection.prototype.dropDatabase = function(callback) {
  var Promise = PromiseProvider.get();
  var _this = this;
  var promise = new Promise.ES6(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (_this.readyState !== STATES.connected) {
      _this.on('open', function() {
        _this.db.dropDatabase(function(error) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          } else {
            resolve();
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      _this.db.dropDatabase(function(error) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    }
  });
  if (callback) {
    promise.then(function() { callback(); }, callback);
  }
  return promise;
};
```

Here's a simple version of the above logic that can be used with earlier Mongoose versions:

```
// This shim is backported from Mongoose 4.6.4 to reliably drop a database
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/42860208/254318
// The first arg should be "mongoose.connection"
function dropDatabase (connection, callback) {
    // readyState 1 === 'connected'
    if (connection.readyState !== 1) {
      connection.on('open', function() {
        connection.db.dropDatabase(callback);
      });
    } else {
      connection.db.dropDatabase(callback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose 4.6.0+:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb')
mongoose.connection.once('connected', () => {
    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
});
```

Passing a callback to connect won't work anymore:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'commandsTakeWriteConcern' of null*

Comment: `connect` returns a promise, so you can add `.then((connection) => { ... });` to the `mongoose.connect`. See: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeEach((done) => {
      mongoose.connection.dropCollection('products',(error ,result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Products Collection is not dropped')
      } else {
        console.log(result)
      }
    done()
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

To drop all documents in a collection:

```
await mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
```

This answer is based off the mongoose index.d.ts file:

```
dropDatabase(): Promise<any>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/${dbname}`, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
        .then((connection) => {
            mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
        });
```

To delete a complete database, just pass the name...
This one is working perfectly fine on version 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Since the remove method is depreciated in the mongoose library we can use the deleteMany function with no parameters passed.

```
Model.deleteMany();
```

This will delete all content of this particular Model and your collection will be empty.

Answer (score -2):

For dropping all documents in a collection:

```
myMongooseModel.collection.drop();
```

as seen in the [tests](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/67c465aac5c864c3004d11d49934605037c8f520/test/shard.test.js#L297)