# Mongoose.js: remove collection or DB

Tags: mongoose

Is it possible to remove collection or entire db using mongoose.js?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yes, although you do it via the native MongoDB driver and not Mongoose itself.  Assuming a required, connected, `mongoose` variable, the native [`Db`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html) object is accessible via `mongoose.connection.db`, and that object provides [`dropCollection`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#dropcollection) and [`dropDatabase`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#dropdatabase) methods.

```js
// Drop the 'foo' collection from the current database
mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection('foo', function(err, result) {...});

// Drop the current database
mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err, result) {...});
```

Comment: Note that these methods return promises as well, so you can do things like `await mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection('foo');` instead of struggling with callbacks

Answer (score 112):

This can now be done in Mongoose.

```
MyModel.collection.drop();
```

Hat tip: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4511

Comment: Is there a way to do this with promises?

Comment: @JohnK: `await MyModel.collection.drop();`. The more interesting question is, how do you only drop if the collection exists? Otherwise, you'll get a misleading and cryptic [`MongoError: ns not found`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136204/mongoerror-ns-not-found-when-try-to-drop-collection#comment99306970_44488227).

Comment: @DanDascalescu you can `catch` the error the promise returns.  `await MyModel.collection.drop().then(() => { ... }).catch(() => { ... })`

Comment: This is the highest rated answer but not treating this as a promise will cause problems if you are seeding something complex.  I called this and then began my recursive seed function.  Drop actually happened in the middle of my seed, so many of my items were missing.  It let to a lot of confusion. Use .then()

Answer (score 13):

For those that are using the [mochajs](https://mochajs.org/) test framework and want to clean all db collections after each test, you can use the following which uses async/await:

```
afterEach(async function () {
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections()

  for (let collection of collections) {
    await collection.remove()
  }
})
```

Comment: collection.remove() is deprecated in favor of await collection.drop()

Comment: Won't this clear the data in my database?

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose references the connection on every model.  So, you may find it useful to also drop the DB or collection off of an individual model.

For example:

```
// Drop the 'foo' collection from the current database
User.db.dropCollection('foo', function(err, result) {...});

// Drop the current database
User.db.dropDatabase(function(err, result) {...});
```

Answer (score 3):

For 5.2.15 version of Mongoose + Mocha tests usage where you need to drop all collections before each test.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
     const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

     for (let collection of collections) {
          // note: collection.remove() has been depreceated.        
          await collection.deleteOne(); 
     }
});
```

Comment: It's much safer to drop collections `before` executing instead of after incase execution is interrupted between test runs or data exists in the database already from manual testing.

Answer (score 2):

If want to drop collection after tests and your test were running in a `docker` container:

```
mongoose = require("mongoose");
...
afterAll(async () => {
  const url = 'mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/my-base-name';
  await mongoose.connect(url)
  await mongoose.connection.collection('collection-name').drop()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I dropped my collections using [Connection.prototype.dropCollection()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-dropCollection)

```js
const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb');
conn.dropCollection("Collection_name",callbacks);
```