# Working with native MongoDB driver using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'd like to perform Drop Database, Drop Collection Index, getIndex() and e.t. such functions using mongoose, nodeJS.

I was looking around the same issues, but haven't got any solutions yet.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11453617/1259510

Answer (score 0):

```
store.collection('sessions',function(err, collection){
   collection.remove({},function(err, removed){
   });
});
```