# dropCollection isn't dropping the collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, q

mongoose 4.0.3
node 0.10.22
mongod db version 3.0.1

I'm trying to drop a collection using moongoose, but it isn't working

```
run: function() {
    return Q(mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test',opts))
    .then(function(data){
        return Q(mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection('departments'))
        .then(function(data2){
            console.log('data2 is ',data2);
            return Q(true);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log('err is',err);
            return Q(false);
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('err is', err);
        return Q(false);
    });
}
```

This returns `data2 is  undefined`

I tried to follow the answers based on this question :[Mongoose.js: remove collection or DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453617/mongoose-js-remove-collection-or-db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use Q this way.

`Q()` turns anything you pass to it into a promise. When you pass in a function call the way you do it, you effectively pass in that function's return value. In other words, just like `Q(3)` will resolve to `3`, `Q(nodefunc(args))` will resolve to whatever `nodefunc(args)` returns - and in case of asynchronous functions that isn't particularly much.

I suppose you want to use `ninvoke` (a.k.a. `nsend`) instead.

> **Q.ninvoke(object, methodName, ...args)**
>
> Alias: `Q.nsend`
>
> Calls a Node.js-style method with the given variadic arguments,
>   returning a promise that is fulfilled if the method calls back with a
>   result, or rejected if it calls back with an error (or throws one
>   synchronously).

The mongoose API docs say that `connect` is a synchronous method that returns nothing. Its close cousin `createConnection` will return a connection object and might be a better fit for the use case.

The following code has both - a call to `Q` for a synchronous method that returns an actual value, and a call to `Q.nsend` for an asynchronous method that works with callbacks.

```
run: function() {
    return Q(mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', opts))
    .then(function(connection){
        return Q.nsend(connection.db, 'dropCollection', 'departments')
        .then(function(data){
            console.log('data is ', data);
            return data;
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('err is', err);
    });
}
```

(untested code)

Comment: `connection` comes out undefined. If you use `mongoose.connection.db` instead of `connection.db` there, it works fine

Comment: @Houseman Ahh, I see. `mongoose.connect` is a synchronous function (didn't know, I don't do a lot with mongoose). In that case you don't need to promisify it at all (unless you want to use Q's `.catch()`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the way mongoose, db and Q can interact.

you can try (not tested)

```
run: function() {
  return Q(mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test',opts).exec())
  .then(function(){
    var db = mongoose.connection.db;
    var drop = Q.nbind(db.dropCollection, db);
    return drop('departments')
           .then(function(data2){
             console.log('data2 is ',data2);
             return true;
            }).catch(function(err){
             console.log('err is',err);
             return false;
             });
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('err is', err);
    return false;
});
```

}

a mongoose function needs to be called with `exec()` in order to return a Promise.

this does not extend to the dropCollection method as far as I know so you need to de-nodeify it.