# MongoError: ns not found when try to drop collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose throw an error i.e, "**MongoError: ns not found**" when i try to drop collection.

Here is my mongoose code:

```
var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
......
......
......   
mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection("myCollection",function(err,affect){
   console.log('err',err);

})
```

Error:

> err { [MongoError: ns not found]
>   name: 'MongoError',
>    message: 'ns
>   not found',
>   ok: 0,
>   errmsg: 'ns not found' }

Comment: You're not connecting to the database (using `mongoose.connect()`).

Comment: mongoose doesn't have drop collection method. chekout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10088410/2165143) answer for more info.

Comment: yes, i have used mongoose.connect(). @robertklep

Comment: @RajeshDhiman, mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection method has used,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453617/mongoose-js-remove-collection-or-db?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 132):

`MongoError: ns not found` occurs when performing actions on collections that don't exist.

For example, attempting to drop indexes before an explicit collection creation has occurred or before adding a document to the collection which implicitly creates the collection.

Comment: So in this case, you cannot drop a collection which doesn't exist in the first place. ns is probably for namespace?

Comment:  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/acd196d77043d007b07b48b6e2c4fb13cfa5b938/src/mongo/db/catalog/drop_collection.cpp#L71

Comment: Who at Mongo, Inc. thought ["ns not found" was a useful error](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1988)?!

Comment: Thanks all, did a check before the drop and wrapped in IF, fixed problem. App is running.

Comment: @DanDascalescu that's so fucking funny

Answer (score 11):

`Status(ErrorCodes::NamespaceNotFound, "ns not found");` is thrown when you try to drop a collection, a view or an index that doesn't exist.

For example: [`_dropCollection`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/d471957fc37ef6cafe9ffeda3e231cdc871c3ce3/src/mongo/db/catalog/drop_collection.cpp#L115)

Other than that, there is no need to explicitly check if a collection already exists before doing any CRUD operations.

Answer (score 5):

This is my mongodb connection interface to avoid drop collection error:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = class {
    static async connect() {
        this.mongoose = require('mongoose');

        await this.mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_DSN, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
            reconnectInterval: 5000,
            useFindAndModify: false
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error('Database connection error: ' + err.message);
        });

        this.db = this.mongoose.connection.db;

        return this.db;
    }

    static async dropCollection(list) {
        if (list.constructor.name !== 'Array') {
            list = [list];
        }

        const collections = (await this.db.listCollections().toArray()).map(collection => collection.name);

        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (collections.indexOf(list[i]) !== -1) {
                await this.db.dropCollection(list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just catch the error if the error is a collection not found error?

Comment: There's a race condition if two similar clients are trying to do the same thing.  Both clients could see that the collection exists and both clients could decide to drop it, and one client will get an error.  This is because `listCollections` and `dropCollection` are distinct requests made to the database, and requests from other clients may be interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I check the collection exists, before attempting to drop.

```
if (db.listCollections().toArray().includes(collection)) {
   await db.collection(collection).drop();
}
```

Comment: Not sure where you're running it, but in node.js I needed to have `if (await db.listCollection().toArray().map(c=>c.name).includes(collection)) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of collections in an async function:

```
(await db.listCollections().toArray()).find(c => c.name === 'myCollection');
```

If not exists, it returns `undefined`, otherwise a `CollectionInfo` object as for example:

```
{
  name: 'myCollection',
  type: 'view',
  options: { viewOn: '...', pipeline: [ [Object] ] },
  info: { readOnly: true }
}
```