# Using sparse: true still getting MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Schema (../models/add.js)

```
var addSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true},
    phone: Number,
    email: String,
    country: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', addSchema);
```

add-manager.js

```
var Add = require('../models/add.js');
var AM = {};
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = AM;

AM.notOwned = function(country, callback)
{
    Add.update({country: country}, {country: country}, {upsert: true}, function(err, res){
        if (err) callback (err);
        else callback(null, res);
    })
}
```

news.js

```
// if country # is not in the database
    AM.notOwned(country, function(error, resp){
        if (error) console.log("error: "+error);
        else 
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    })
```

error:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: bot.contacts.$name_1  dup key: { : null }
```

After seeing the error message, I googled around and learned that when the document is created, since name isn't set, its treated as null. [See Mongoose Google Group Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoose-orm/znNF_F-kl6o)   The first time AM.notOwned is called it will work as there isn't any documents in the collection without a name key.  AM.notOwned will then insert a document with an ID field, and a country field.

Subsequent AM.notOwned calls fails because there is already a document with no name field, so its treated as name: null, and the second AM.notOwned is called fails as the field "name" is not set and is treated as null as well; thus it is not unique.

So, following the advice of the Mongoose thread and reading the [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-sparse) I looked at using sparse: true.  However, its still throwing the same error. Further looking into it, I thought it may be the same issue as: [this](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/421), but setting schema to name: {type: String, index: {unique: true, sparse: true}} doesn't fix it either.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454178/mongoerror-erre11000-duplicate-key-error) S.O. question/answer leads me to believe it could be caused by the index not being correct, but I'm not quite sure how to read the the db.collection.getIndexes() from Mongo console.

```
db.contacts.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "bot.contacts",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "name" : 1
        },
        "unique" : true,
        "ns" : "bot.contacts",
        "name" : "name_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    }
]
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to drop the old, non-sparse index in the shell so that Mongoose can recreate it with `sparse: true` the next time your app runs.

```
> db.contacts.dropIndex('name_1')
```

Comment: db.contacts.dropIndex() worked.  Although, I tried using db.contacts.reIndex() and that didn't fix it.  Thanks for your prompt and concise answer.  I couldn't for the life of me figure out what I was doing wrong and searched everywhere.