# How to stop mongoose find if request has been canceled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, request

I have front with axios and back with node + mongoose.

At front I can [cancel](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) my request, but at back I have such row

```
const data = await BigCollection.find({});
```

And it *continues to wait* answer from db. 
**Can I abort this find?**

Comment: you can not abort it

Comment: @SaikatHajra for such case should I use another tool like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240327/how-to-run-db-killop-using-the-mongodb-native-node-js-driver)?

Comment: not sure certainly whether it will work. Mostly not. you can close the connection if required for a while and reconnect.