# How to drop database with node mongoose ?

Tags: mongoose

I want to remove dirty data in the database (the database & the collections) , However the following code is not work ? How could I drop database with mongoose ?

```
console.log(uri) // uri = mongodb://localhost/dev 

var db = mongoose.connect(uri,function(err){
  if (err) console.log(err) // no err output
});

mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){ //db.connection is not work too .
  mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err){
  console.log(err); // no err output 
  });
});
```

All my data and database are still not deleted .

Comment: I initially closed this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081452/drop-database-with-mongoose but it looks like you're already using that approach so I reopened it.  What do you mean by "db.connection is not work too"?

Comment: var db = mongoose.connect(uri,function(err){
      if (err) console.log(err) // no err output
    });

    db.connection.on('open', function(){ //db.connection is not work too .
      mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err){
          console.log(err); // no err output 
      });
    });

Comment: No version of Mongoose was provided, but this question is over 2 years old, so it has likely expired.