# Can't drop mongo database through mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to drop an entire database using mongoose. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081452/drop-database-with-mongoose) answer here, but it only suggests dropping individual collections, not actually answering the question.

I tried making a sample javascript to see what is wrong:

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ngl_dev'
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(url);

// Trying to drop the entire database, doesn't work
/*
mongoose.connections[0].db.dropDatabase(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Database dropped");
});
*/

// But dropping individual collections does.
/*
mongoose.connections[0].collections.TestTypes.drop(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Collection dropped');
});
*/

// I can drop the entire database using mongodb module, but I don't have
// access to it in my production code, so this is just an example.
/*
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the server');
    db.dropDatabase();
    console.log('Dropped database');
    db.close();
});
*/
```

When I uncomment the first section, nothing happens, the script hangs, and all the data in the collections and the collections themselves still remain, contrary to what I would expect to happen from running that function.

When I uncomment the second section, I get an error saying that the collection `TestType` is undefined, which I guess makes sense since I'm not using the mongoose schema provided in the application. So when I run the same code and require the right schemas, `collection dropped` gets printed to the console, the data in the specified collection gets dropped, but the collection itself still remains and the script hangs.

When I uncomment the third section, the specified database actually gets dropped, which is what I would expect to happen for the first section of code. However, this script is being run in a different section of the production code that doesn't have direct access to the `mongodb` module, so this is just an example to show that mongoose is not working correctly.

How can I get mongoose to drop the entire database with the `dropDatabase()` function?

Essentially what I am trying to do is replace a bash script that uses the mongo shell with something that works cross platform.

Comment: So `mongoose.connection` will give you a point to reference the underlying driver object, **BUT** the way mongoose works means that connection is not necessarily defined until something has happened that actually causes a connection to the database. The safe way to "esure" connection is to place all that code in an event handler `mongoose.connection.once("open", function() { //code using underlying driver directly })`

Comment: So dropDatabase is basically a no-op?

Comment: That's not what I said. You need to ensure the connection is in place "before" you call underlying driver methods. The methods on mongoose models acutally do this "behind the scenes". So the `mongoose.connect()` does not actually "connect", it just sets up the connection information for the time when the connection is actually established. Hence `mongoose.connection.once("open",function())` actually fires when the connection is "really" made. Then it's safe to use driver references.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do it like you want, but you can

```
for (var collection in mongoose.connection.collections){
    collection.drop( function(err) {
        console.log('collection dropped');
    });
}
```

Comment: Then what is the point of db.dropDatabase() if it doesn't work? This sounds like a bug that ought to be reported.

Comment: Of course you can refernce the `db` object. It's just another reference from the underlying node driver.