# Cannot read property 'drop' of undefined in simple migration

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, migrate-mongo

I'm using the [migrate-mongo library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate-mongo) and have this simple migration to create a view. However I'm getting an error on migrate down.

`ERROR: Could not migrate down 20220620114132-CreateContentView.js: Cannot read property 'drop' of undefined`

```
module.exports = {
  async up(db, client) {
    db.createCollection('content', {
      viewOn: 'assets',
      pipeline: [...stuff]
    })
  },

  async down(db, client) {
    db.content.drop()
  }
}
```

I notice that this question has the same error: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'drop' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759516/typeerror-cannot-read-property-drop-of-undefined)

However they're using mongoose where this isn't (shouldn't be)

Answer (score 0):

I mixed up the mongodb terminal commands with node.js syntax. The drop line should be `db.collection('content').drop()`